# COUNT(DISTINCT()) Return false value

Tags: sql-server, count, distinct

I try to count total employee in my subquery table. Suppose the count result will return 0, but it keeps returning 1.

If I try to return only employee_id and month together, I didn't get any return value for may which is correct, but each time I try to count(distinct), I will get 1 as my return value. This is my sql

```
SELECT

  count (distinct(CASE WHEN (x.month =5 and x.employee_id <> 0) THEN 
  x.employee_id
        ELSE 0 END)) as test_may
FROM(
 (
SELECT 

     h.month,
     h.employee_id,
     eb.employee_no,
     ee.company_code,
     h.amount,   
     h.year, 
     h.trx_type,   
     h.trx_code, 
     v.trx_desc,
    h.frequency,
    h.run_sequence

FROM 
    v_employee h,
    v_trans v,
    employee_emp ee, 
    employee eb          
  WHERE
        ( h.year = 2014 ) AND  
        ( h.employee_id = ee.employee_id ) AND  
        ( ee.employee_id = eb.employee_id ) AND 
        ( h.employee_no = eb.employee_no ) AND 
        ( h.trx_code = v.trx_code ) AND
        ( h.trx_type = v.trx_type ) AND
        ( v.company_code = ee.company_code OR v.company_code is NULL) AND
        ( h.trx_type IN ('S','B','N','O','A','D','L') )
)
)x,
employee_emp ee,
employee eb

 WHERE

    ( x.employee_id = ee.employee_id ) AND
    ( ee.employee_id = eb.employee_id ) AND
    ( x.employee_no = eb.employee_no ) AND
     ( x.year = 2014 )
```

Comment: Mysql is not SQL-Server, so i deleted the tag

Comment: COUNT DISTINCT isn't broken, nor is SQL, the language. What are your data, what did you expect and what did you get? If 1 row is returned, the result will be 1

Comment: The result is just depend on your second query.. much better to check it at your own.

Comment: There's nothing wrong. Your DISTINCT returns only a value of 0. Then you count the values returned. There's only one value returned (0), so you have 1 value.

Comment: Did you confuse COUNT and SUM perhaps? Even a result of `0` is still 1 result, so `COUNT(0)` will return 1. Why don't you use a `GROUP BY` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `count` as you have it now will also count the 0 that is in the `ELSE` clause of the `CASE` expression. Even with `DISTINCT` still one instance of that 0 will be counted.

Remove the  `ELSE 0` so that you have `NULL` -- which is not counted:

```
count (distinct(CASE WHEN x.month =5 and x.employee_id <> 0
                     THEN x.employee_id
                END)) as test_may
```

Note that with `NULLIF` you can shorten this expression to:

```
count (distinct(CASE x.month WHEN 5 THEN NULLIF(x.employee_id, 0) END)) as test_may
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `count` will return the same count even in both cases. Because you are giving the value for Count function in both the cases.

Change from

```
 count (distinct(CASE WHEN (x.month =5 and x.employee_id <> 0) THEN 
  x.employee_id
        ELSE 0 END))
```

To

```
 count (distinct(CASE WHEN (x.month =5 and x.employee_id <> 0) THEN 
  x.employee_id
        ELSE NULL END))
```

Count will just count the values whether it is 0 or 100 as 1 & skip null values while counting. So in the Else condition `NULL` will give you correct output.